# How should I change the cell color according to a specific price?

Tags: php, html

I want to change the color of the entire cell according to a specific value. But what should I do when the grammar is wrong and it doesn't work?

in this my code

```
   echo "<tr  if( $row['treatment_fees_check_division'] == 'error') : style='yellow' >";
                echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['chart_num'] . "</td>"; 
                echo "<td>" . $row['chart_name'] . "</td>";                                        
                echo "<td>" .  substr($row['visit'], 0,10) . "</td>";
                echo "<td >" .  number_format($row['total_medical_bills']) . "</td>";
                echo "<td >" .  number_format($row['total_amount']) . "</td>";   
                echo "<td>" .  number_format($row['amount_asked']) . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .  number_format($row['medical_bills_payment']) . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .  number_format($row['personal_liability_amount']) . "</td>";                                                  
                echo "<td >" .  number_format($row['non_payment']) . "</td>";
                echo "<td >" .  number_format($row['non_payment_sales']) . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['insurance_division'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['division'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .  number_format($row['cash_amount_received']) . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .  number_format($row['cash_receipt']) . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .  number_format($row['cash_receipt_non_payment']) . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .  number_format($row['cash_receipt_payment']) . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .  number_format($row['card_amount_received']) . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .  number_format($row['card_non_payment']) . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .  number_format($row['card_payment']) . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .  number_format($row['treatment_fees_difference']) . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .  $row['treatment_fees_check_division'] . "</td>";                
                echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your first line with something like this.

```
if ($row['treatment_fees_check_division'] == 'error') {
     echo "<tr style='yellow' >";
} else {
     echo "<tr >";
}
```